# Android: Should I use if condition when I replace deprecated method?

Tags: java, android, sdk, deprecated

With new android API some methods deprecated.

-so What that mean ?
-Should I use if condition to check which method to use ? (the deprecated one or the new one) for example :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    return resources.getDrawable(id, context.getTheme());
} else {
    return resources.getDrawable(id);
}
```

Or when I replace the deprecated method by the new one it automatically work for all the API ?
**thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Using a deprecated method is a bad idea on newer platforms. But you can still use it if you want to. But for when you want to use the newest, using an if-statement is probably the best way to do the check.

Just one thing: Create a local integer in the class and when you create the class, it is initialized. That way you don't need to make repeated calls to an external source.

Comment: thank you for help 
sorry but I didn't understand the one thing ,could you  explain it more ?

Comment: What is that one thing?

Comment: Create a local integer in the class and when I create the class, it is initialized. That way I don't need to make repeated calls to an external source.

Comment: In your class, you create a new integer: `int userApi;` and when you create the class: `userApi = Build.Version.SDK_INT;`

Comment: You can skip it though. You can continue to make calls to Build.Version.SDK_INT, but I find it easier to declare it as an integer locally instead of having to write a lot of text